# Assertion botch: negative time oracle 11

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, timestamp-with-timezone

my java application is trying to run an insert query to an oracle DB.
the table i am inserting to has a DATE field called last_modified
my query uses Timestamp, while counting on the oracle to convert to date field.
every day at 23:00 i get the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: **Assertion botch: negative time**
at
oracle.jdbc.driver.DateCommonBinder.setOracleHMS(OraclePreparedStatement.java:18740)
    at
oracle.jdbc.driver.TimestampBinder.bind(OraclePreparedStatement.java:19245)
    at
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setupBindBuffers(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3014)
    at
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9973)
    at
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:213)
```

i have checked the time zones using:

```
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DBTIMEZONE, SESSIONTIMEZONE FROM DUAL;
```

i got: `05-JUN-13 08.09.29.244232 AM +02:00, 05-JUN-13 08.09.29.244236 AM +02:00, +00:00,+02:00`

the client mochine( the one on which i have the java application) and the DB machine are the same one. but still i get the `java.lang.RuntimeException: Assertion botch: negative time`

my questions are:

1. how can i add to my code a catch block that will avoid the need to restart my application every day at 23:00 ? it seems to me that the exception is an `java.lang.RuntimeException` and i cant add `catch(java.lang.RuntimeException e)` or can i ?
2. is the `Assertion botch: negative time` an assertion ? can i catch it using `catch (java.lang.AssertionError e)` ?
3. i read, that after changing the linux time zone i should run a restart  on the machine. till then the oracle will not use the new time zone. is there a way for me to know what is configured and what timezone the oracle is using ?
   thanks.

Comment: Your error is not fully pasted. And you should not catch `RuntimeException`s. Can you show some code?

Comment: I would not recommend any try/catch block as it would be a dirty patch. You should find out the real reason why this is happening, maybe posting the code block where the error occurs. I am thinking that you might have some time conversion going on that's not doing it's job properly.

Comment: sorry, i cannot paste my code, but all i am doing is inserting java Timestamp class into a oracle Date field.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. We fixed it by using vm parametr to explicitly set Java timezone.

```
-Duser.timezone=<yourTZ>
```

This is a strange bug, when Date objects are correct on the other end, but still bug when time falls into TZ gap.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the version of your connector. In case you are using ojdbc, change to a newer version. I had the same issue, i was using ojdbc6. All worked fine after i upgraded to 12.1.0.1